# how to debug data query in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is a beginner question, but I searched for an hour and couldn't find an answer. 
I am trying to write a simple data query which I included in my HomeController

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

        public function showWelcome()
        {
                return View::make('hello');
        }

}
$programs=DB::table('node')->where('type', 'Programs')->get();
```

$programs is undefined so I am guessing that my query didn't work but I have no idea how to debug it. I tried installing firebug and phpbug and chromphp tools but they don't seem to show anything. My apache log doesn't show anything either. Am I missing something? How do I debug this?

Comment: what do you want to do with that query ? pass it to the view ?

Comment: yes I want to print a list of programs.title

Comment: You may want to look at the [laracast](https://laracasts.com/) videos. I think these are going to help you.

Comment: DB::getQueryLog() will show you the raw mysql queries. Or if you want a more robust solution, this in-browser console is really good, which is accessible by going to *mylaravelapp.com*/console.  Installation instructions, https://github.com/darsain/laravel-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an expression outside of a method when using a class, instead you need to put it inside a method like:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function getPrograms()
    {
        $programs = DB::table('node')->where('type', 'Programs')->get();

        // pass the $programs to the programs view for showing it
        return View::make('programs')->with('programs', $programs);
    }

}
```

So, for example, if you have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/programs', 'HomeController@getPrograms');
```

Then you may use an `URL` like: `example.com/programs` to invoke the `getPrograms` method in the class `HomeController`.

Probably this answer doesn't help much but I think you should learn the basics ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)) first so read books and articles online and check the `Laravel` website to read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the result of that query to the view like so:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        $programs = DB::table('node')->where('type', 'Programs')->get();

        return View::make('hello', array('programs' => $programs));
    }
}
```

And in your view you will have access to the $programs variable.

Comment: I forgot that variables needed to be passed into the view!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If i'm missing the point, but can't you use the "dd($programs)" to check what is or not is inside the variable?